# How to pass query parameter array using Angular $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I'm trying to enable a feature where users can be searched for based on multiple tags (an array of tags) using the following structure:

```
GET '/tags/users?tag[]=test&tag[]=sample'
```

I have this working on my node server and have successfully tested it using Postman. The issue I'm running into is how to structure this `GET` request in my Angular service using `$resource`. I have found documentation for `$http` stating that adding `params:{'tag[]': tag}` to the request object will do the trick, but cannot find anything regarding `$resource`.

Comment: Have you looked into $location and search()? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: Just took a look, thanks. I'm not changing location at all, I'm simply returning a list of results within the current page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In angular you can pass array as query string using `$resource`

**In controller:**

```
    angular.module('myApp').controller('userController',['$scope','userService', '$location',
        function($scope, userService, $location){
            $scope.searchQuery = {};

            $scope.SearchUsers = function() {
                $scope.roles = ['admin', 'register', 'authenticate'];
                $scope.searchQuery.name ='xxx';
                $scope.searchQuery['roles[]'] = $scope.roles;
                userService.searchUsers($scope.searchQuery)
                    .$promise.then(function (response) {
                        $scope.users = response.users;
                    });
            };
       }
   ]);
```

**In service:**

```
    angular.module('myApp').factory('userService', ['$resource',
  function($resource) {

    return {
        searchUsers: function(searchQuery){
            var searchRequest = $resource('/auth/search/user', {}, {
                'get': {method: 'GET'}
            });
            return searchRequest.get(searchQuery);
        }
    };
  }
]);
```

the request url like:

```
/auth/search/users?name=xxx&roles%5B%5D=admin&roles%5B%5D=register&roles%5B%5D=authenticate
```

you get `%5B%5D` instead of `[]` in your request url

and if you expect return `array` instead of `object` then you should use

```
'get': {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
```